# True /false question about compact set in real analysis

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

This question was a true /false question in my real analysis quiz today and I am unable to provide a reason for it.

Question is : A closed and bounded subset of complete metric space is compact.

I think it is not compact but only because any open cover may not have finite subcover but I am unable to provide a counterexample for the same.

Comment: the proposed duplicate shows that totally bounded and complete implies compact, but in contrast the answer here shows that a closed and bounded subset of a complete metric space is not necessarily compact

Comment: @J.W Tanner so that means some people are wrongly associating it with different question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a counterexample, you can consider $[0,1]$ with the discrete metric $d(x,y) = 1$ if $x \ne y$, $d(x,y) = 0$ if $x = y$.  This is complete because any Cauchy sequence is eventually constant and hence convergent, but the open cover $\{B(x,\frac 12) : x \in [0,1]\}$ has no finite subcovers because each ball $B(x, \frac 12) = \{x\}$ is a singleton.

Comment: so you mean a ball of radius 1/2 around a point x , is a cover of x but it doesn't have a finite subcover? How? B( x, 1/2) is a single point in itself so why doesn't there exists a finite subcover?

Comment: @user You take one (singleton) ball for each point in $[0, 1]$, and you get a cover of $[0, 1]$ with (uncountably) infinitely many open sets. Such a cover has no proper subcover (removing any $\{x\}$ from the cover will leave $x$ uncovered), let alone finite subcovers.